# How do I add a PrivacyParameter to a PhotoUpdate in facebook4J for Android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I am able to successfully upload a photo to Facebook using:

```
PhotoUpdate post = new PhotoUpdate(new Media(image));
post.setMessage(status);
post_id = facebook.postPhoto(post);
```

How can I add a PrivacyParameter to this?

With a standard PostUpdate I can call

```
post.setPrivacy(privacy);
```

but don't see this method for `PhotoUpdate`

PLEASE HELP?